# facebook webhook verification failed

Tags: java, facebook, servlets, ssl

Trying to do a facebook message bot testing.
Setup a working https://www.mydoamin.com successfully. (bought SSL from namecheap's comodo, DV(domain validation), which is the most basic SSL product. it is said DV/SSL is sufficient for facebook app.). It is a real public web site and working fine through https. tested.

After I clicked " verify and save" button on webhook setup page, got the error info from Facebook Webhook verification:
"The URL couldn't be validated. Callback verification failed with the following errors: curl_errno = 35; curl_error = error:14082174:SSL routines:ssl3_check_cert_and_algorithm:dh key too small; HTTP Status Code = 200; HTTP Message = Connection established. "
(but on my server side, I did not see any log info, i.e. seems facebook platform did not really interact with my app server before it concluded the verification falied....???)

My java server code for handling webhook callback testing is the following:

public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

```
    log.info("MyIS FB Webhook callback starts...");

    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    String selectedScreen = request.getServletPath();
    String VALIDATION_TOKEN = "WebhookToken";

    try {
      if(selectedScreen.equals("/webhook")){
        log.info("/webhook starts....");
        if (request.getParameter("hub.mode").equals("subscribe") &&
         request.getParameter("hub.verify_token").equals(VALIDATION_TOKEN) {
           response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
           PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
           out.write(request.getParameter("hub.challenge"));
           out.flush();
           out.close();  
          } else {
             log.info("/webhook failed....");
             response.setStatus(403);          
          }  
     }
   } catch(Exception e){
    log.info(".....");
   }
   log.info(".....");
```

}

Could anyone tell me what's going wrong? what I missed?
Thank you for any help!
Best Regards

Comment: Add some more specific info about my facebook webhook testing: 1) the call back url is: https://www. mydomain.com/webhook; 2) if I enter the address, i.e. https://www. mydomain.com/webhook on any web browser, I can see the log info at my server machine, e.g. /webhook starts...., which means the server app works fine. But when I use facebook message webhook setup page, to do verification, i.e. click "verify and save" button, my app server did not show any info. seems the facebook platform did not really call my web server...is it a facebook message platform bug?

Answer (score 1):

Finally, after one week struggling with the issue, find the solution to this issue, i.e. facebook message/webhook verification error/complain: ....dh key too small.....

1. Root Cause: my web application server has sslv3 enabled, and some week cipher suites.
2. Solution: to fix the problem, need disable sslv3, enable TLSv1 and above, specify the strong cipher suites to be used by the web application server.
3. How I did it:
   a) upgrade my linux server from centOS5.6 to centOS6.8
   b) upgrade the jdk from 1.6 to 1.7
   c) on my web application server's configuration file, server.xml, specify the strong cipher suites to be used, sth like: 
   sslProtocol="TLSv1"
   SSLHonorCipherOrder="On"      ciphers="TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256"
4. Result: facebook/message/webhook verify-safe shows: "green-complete"-:)
   (the code is straight and correct, nothing wrong about it. it is the server ssl env. has be to solid.)

Answer (score 0):

> curl_error = error:14082174:SSL
>   routines:ssl3_check_cert_and_algorithm:**dh key too small**;

Did you generate a 2048-bit RSA key for your SSL certificate?

This looks like a relevant KB article from your certificate provider:

https://support.comodo.com/index.php?/Default/Knowledgebase/Article/View/689/17/your-rsa-key-is-too-small-or-this-csr-uses-an-unsupported-key-size

Comment: Hi, ck1, thank you for the quick help! I did use 2048-bit key for creating my ssl certificate. basically, I run: keytool -genkey -keysize 2048 -keyalg RSA -alias tomcat -keystore mykeystore.jks to create initial keystore, then create CSR, then create/activate SSl certificate. Any other problem you may think of?